# Como ler o resultado de um ficheiro para uma variável passando parâmetros POST?

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

Podemos obter o resultado da execução de uma URL para uma variável utilizando a função [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php):

```php
<?php
$pagina = file_get_contents('http://www.meusite.com/');
echo $pagina;
?>
```

Mas como podemos extender esta funcionalidade, passando parâmetros do tipo `POST` na requisição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira é fazer uso das funções [stream_context_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stream-context-create.php) e [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-build-query.php) que nos vão permitir criar um contexto de fluxo e gerar uma consulta de HTML. Depois basta aplicar tudo isso como parâmetros da função `file_get_contents()`:

#### Função

```php
/**
 * Get File Stream Data
 *
 * Executa um POST ao ficheiro indicado devolvendo o
 * output gerado pelo mesmo.
 *
 * @param string $postdata Parametros para enviar como POST ao ficheiro
 * @param string $filepath Caminho de URL completo para o ficheiro
 *
 * @return string Resultado do POST ao ficheiro indicado
 */
function getFileStreamData ($postdata, $filepath) {

    // preparar a matriz de opções
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' . "\r\n",
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    // criar o contexto de fluxo
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    // devolver os resultados do ficheiro com a realização de um POST
    return file_get_contents($filepath, false, $context);
}
```

#### Utilização

```php
<?php

// criar a consulta a enviar para a página
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        "parametro1" => 'john',
        "parametro2" => 'doe',
        "parametro3" => 'bananas'
    )
); 

// recolher a página enviando os parâmetros de consulta
$result = getFileStreamData ($postdata, 'http://www.site.pt/caminho/para/ficheiro.php');

?>
```

Desta forma, estamos a ler o resultado do ficheiro `ficheiro.php` como se tivesse sido realizado um `POST` ao mesmo.